# How to override or extend template and layout files for an extension downloaded by composer?

Tags: magento2, layout, overrides, extend, template-override

I have an extension that is downloaded through composer, there are two files i would like to update. How to I **override/extend** the files? what is the correct paths i need to create in `app/design/frontend/` folder?

The paths for the files i want to change are:

```
/vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

and

```
/vendor/amasty/module-faq-product-questions/view/frontend/templates/pages/question_view.phtml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily override these file in your theme as:

```
app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/Amasty_Faq/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

app/design/frontend/{PackageName}/{ThemeName}/Amasty_Faq/templates/pages/question_view.phtml
```

Comment: Can you check again the answer? I'm using infortis ultimo theme, so should i put them under "app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Module_Faq_Product_Questions/" or "app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Faq_Product_Questions/", do i not need to use the vendor name "Amasty" in the folder path?

Comment: You Need to use : `app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Faq_Product_Questions/`

Comment: figured out, the correct path is "/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Amasty_Faq/". From the catalog_product_view.xml it has a comment says the package name is: @package Amasty_Faq. thanks though